# Why eslint does not check JS?

Tags: javascript, gulp, eslint

Eslint loads, but does not fix 'problem js'...
File eslint.config.json

```
    {
  "ecmaFeatures": {
    "jsx": true
  },
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "node": true,
    "jquery": true
  },
  "rules": {
    "quotes": 0,
    "no-trailing-space": 0,
    "eol-last": 0,
    "no-unused-vars":0,
    "no-underscore-dangle":0,
    "no-alert": 0,
    "no-lone-blocks": 0
  },
  "globals": {
    jQuery: true,
    $ : true
  }
}
```

In JS file i can use global variables... 
Lint does not check JS.

Comment: Please provide additional details (i.e. how you're running eslint)

Comment: [gulpfile.js](https://jsfiddle.net/vhnfc3bd/) @Mchl

Comment: What does `gulp lint` output?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using version newer then 1.0.0 none of the rules are enabled by default. Since your config above only shows disabling rules, that means eslint runs with no enabled rules, and as such, doesn't find any errors. What you might want to do is add the following line to your config:

```
{
  "extends": "eslint:recommended"
}
```

which will enabled all of the rules marked as recommended on [this page](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/).
Or you can also extend from existing configs that you can find on NPM by searching for `eslint-config-`

Comment: I use "gulp-eslint": "~1.0.0" . Adding:
  `"extends": "eslint:recommended"`  does not help me...

Comment: In that case, you will need to provide more details. Like what does your gulp script for eslint looks like? Do you pass config file to it directly, since "eslint.config.json" is not a standard name, it will not be picked up automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. Adding below line in the .eslintrc helped:

```
"extends": ["eslint:recommended", "plugin:react/recommended"]
```

Note: extends option might be already there but without the plugin option.